# CGColorSpaceCreateIndexed create grayscale colour space with alpha

Tags: ios, alpha, grayscale, cgcolorspace

Can somebody advice how to create grayscale colour space with alpha using `CGColorSpaceCreateIndexed` method? I need only grayscale values but with alpha channel enabled, that's why CG`ColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()` does not work for me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()` should create a WA color space just like `CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()` should return RGBA. But if that doesn't work, what do you get when you try something like `CGColorGetColorSpace([UIColor whiteColor].CGColor)`?

Comment: Using `CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace2 = CGColorGetColorSpace([UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);` in  `CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil,
                                                 width,
                                                 height,
                                                 8,
                                                 0,
                                                 colorSpace2,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaFirst);` returns invalid context.

Comment: That color space should work with that function, since it's not an indexed color space, but make sure to use that `bitmapInfo` parameter correctly ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGBitmapContextCreate)).